# Why doesn't the pseudo class :active work?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

My webpage has a [Bootstrap dropdown button](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) which I gave four dropdown-items to. Each of them was given a javascript event which lets to dynamically translate some elements of the page (therefore the four dropdown-items were named "en", "es", "fr", "it"):

```
<div class="btn-group">
                <button id="translate" type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fas fa-language"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#lang-en" onclick="window.lang.change('it');return false;">It</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#lang-en" onclick="window.lang.change('fr');return false;">Fr</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#lang-en" onclick="window.lang.change('en');return false;">En</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#lang-en" onclick="window.lang.change('es');return false;">Es</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want to change the style of the four dropdown-items when a language is selected. For instance, when the user clicks on the "fr" dropdown-item the elements of the page are translated in French; and when her/he open the dropdown menu again the item "fr" is given the color blue.

This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

[image: example]

I want the color of that dropdown item to remain blue the whole time the language of the page is "French".

I've been trying to use the CSS pseudo-class `:active` to achieve this goal but it didn't work:

```
.dropdown-item:active{
    background-color: black;
    color: blue;
}
```

More specifically, the background-color is converted to "black" only when the item is clicked, whereas I want it to remain black until when another language is selected.

Am I using the wrong pseudo-class or should I opt for another CSS selector or alternative method?

Comment: I think when that dropdown item is selected, bootstrap adds another class called `active`, you should select it in css as `.dropdown-item .active` and see if it works.

Comment: `:active` means "While being activated". It's designed for effects like "When you click a button, it looks like it is pushed down, and when you stop clicking, it pops back up again".

Comment: thanks @Quentin. Might I use ':visited' instead?

Comment: No, because that is "URL exists in the history" so every language version the user had visited would be matched.

Answer (score 1):

`:active` means "While being activated". It's designed for effects like "When you click a button, it looks like it is pushed down, and when you stop clicking, it pops back up again".

There is no pseudo-class for "The last one of a group of buttons, each of which run JavaScript, that was clicked on".

---

You've expressed your question in the form of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so let's step back to the actual problem:

*How can I select the link that points to the current language version of the document?*

First, make your JavaScript unobtrusive.

```
<a class="dropdown-item" 
   href="/it/this/document"
   hreflang="it"><abbr title="Italian">It</abbr></a>

<script>
    const langlinks = Array.from(document.querySelector(".dropdown-item"));
    langlinks.forEach(link => link.addEventListener("click", changeLang);
    function changelang (event) {
        window.lang.change(event.target.hreflang);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
```

Then make sure that when you change language, you express it in the markup:

```
<html lang="it">
```

Then you can write a selector using the [language pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#lang-pseudo):

```
html:lang(it) .dropdown-menu[hreflang=it] {
    /* ... */
}
```

Sadly, we can't map the two instances of `it` there programmatically with CSS, so you'll need to include a selector for each language.